# Can Baking AO be done with Eevee?

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, texture-baking

So far I have been doing this with Cycles, as it is shown in this [YT tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zum2jlruecw&t=5s)
If you're familiar baking AO with Cycles, it's that method where you create a 2nd UV map, and a 2nd Img Texture node but it is not plugged to the rest of the nodes, etc
This method works, no doubt. But Eevee is so much faster than Cycles. It would be nice to be able to use Eevee for this.

Comment: Nope, no baking panel in eevee.

Comment: :( - Any idea if that is coming in 2020 ?

Comment: Eevee use GTAO which is a screen-space solution. That means it's view dependent and so, can't really be baked (as far as I kow/understand).